# Writing onto a file in Prolog

Tags: file, prolog

Hi I have the following code:

```
show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol) :-
    show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,1), nl.

show_result(_,MaxRow,_,Row) :- Row > MaxRow, !.
show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row) :- 
    show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row,1), nl,
    Row1 is Row+1, show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row1).

show_result(_,_,MaxCol,_,Col) :- Col > MaxCol, !. 
show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row,Col) :- 
    (memberchk(sq(Row,Col,X),Squares), !, write(X); write('#')),
    Col1 is Col+1, show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row,Col1).
```

When I run the code it shows the correct output on the screen.

But I want to write it to a file for which I have modified the code in this way:

```
show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,SolutionFile) :-
   show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,1,SolutionFile),
   open(SolutionFile,write,Stream),
   nl(Stream), close(Stream).

show_result(_,MaxRow,_,Row,SolutionFile) :- Row > MaxRow, !.
show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row,SolutionFile) :- 
   show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row,1,SolutionFile),
   open(SolutionFile,write,Stream),nl(Stream), close(Stream),
   Row1 is Row+1,
   show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row1,SolutionFile).

show_result(_,_,MaxCol,_,Col,SolutionFile) :- Col > MaxCol, !. 
show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row,Col,SolutionFile) :- 
   (  memberchk(sq(Row,Col,X),Squares),
      !,
      open(SolutionFile,write,Stream), write(Stream,X), close(Stream)
   ;  open(SolutionFile,write,Stream), write(Stream,'#'), close(Stream)
   ),
   Col1 is Col+1,
   show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row,Col1,SolutionFile).
```

This returns 'true' but doesn't write anything to the file.
What do I need to change to get the output written to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although this seems overly inefficient, you could try to change the open/3 mode, from `write` to `append`.

Much better would be to pass around the file descriptor, instead of SolutionFile. So I would suggest

```
show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,SolutionFile) :-
   open(SolutionFile,write,Stream),
   show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,1,Stream),
   nl(Stream), close(Stream).
```

and remove all other open/3 from those predicates, writing instead into `SolutionFile`:

```
how_result(_,MaxRow,_,Row,SolutionFile) :- Row > MaxRow, !.
show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row,SolutionFile) :- 
   show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row,1,SolutionFile),
   nl(SolutionFile),
   Row1 is Row+1,
   show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row1,SolutionFile).

show_result(_,_,MaxCol,_,Col,SolutionFile) :- Col > MaxCol, !. 
show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row,Col,SolutionFile) :- 
   (  memberchk(sq(Row,Col,X),Squares),
      !,
      write(SolutionFile,X)
   ;  write(SolutionFile,'#')
   ),
   Col1 is Col+1,
   show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row,Col1,SolutionFile).
```

note: untested code.

Since you mention that the output is already correct, an alternative, available in SWI-Prolog, would be to keep the origincal program unchanged, and call it using [with_output_to](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=with_output_to/2).

Another alternative, use old fashioned IO, prefixing execution with tell/1, and resume after execution with told/0. But this IO modality is deprecated, since it leads to several difficulties...

Comment: I just changed the "write" to "append" and it worked perfectly fine. Write basically overwrites the already written file. Hence, the final output had nothing in it. Changing it to append worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use your original program and:

```
..., once_to_file(show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol)), ...

once_to_file(Goal, File) :-
   open(File, write, S),
   with_output_to(S,once(Goal)),
   close(S).
```

This can be further improved using `setup_call_cleanup/3`.

But seriously, it would be much better for you to "write" the information into a list via a [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg). In this manner you would have a clean, program for this part too.